Write output in ClassInitialize and ClassCleanUp in VS2022
I have tests made with MsTest v2 in which I use [ClassCleanup] to log some summary information. The thing is, contrary to [TestCleanup] that ends up in each individual test summary, it doesn't seem to get recorded anywhere in the UI.
Where can I see the output of _globalTestContext.WriteLine(...); (where _globalTestContext comes from public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)) using Visual Studio 2022?
Note: The question was asked earlier and an answer was provided for previous versions of Visual Studio but now that we have the Test Explorer Window instead of the Test Results Window, it doesn't seem to work anymore.
How to write output in the [ClassInitialize()] of a Unit Test class?

Write logs to a file instead of relying on the TestContext's WriteLine method. In the ClassCleanup method, write the log content to a file, and then check the file after the tests have run.
[ClassCleanup]
public static void ClassCleanup()
{
    File.AppendAllText("c:\temp\MyTest.txt", "Your log message here.");
}

When running these tests in Visual Studio, the output from the ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup methods usually doesn't appear in the results of individual tests. This is why you might need to use other methods to view the output from these methods.
